# Detect 'Allow app to launch' Window JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I am developing a SharePoint App that basically launches a form in a Windows 8 application once the action is clicked. This is working perfectly fine. However, once you select this action, you are redirected to a page that basically holds some parameters to launch the app. This page throws a window that asks the user if it's okay to launch the app:

[image]

How can I detect if this has been launched or not? Ultimately I'd like to detect if the user hits 'Allow' or 'Cancel' but either scenario will work. I am trying to redirect a user to the parent page once this window has launched (hopefully when the user clicks 'Allow'

Is this possible? I found a helpful thread here: http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/55730/

However, this thread is very useful but doesn't give me the answer I need. I've tried using jQuerys `.blur` and this works(ish). It isn't giving me a consistent response but looks like it's a step in the right direction (if I can't detect the window that launches). I've also tried the following code by using `.hover` but am receiving inconsistent results.

```
$(window).hover(function (event) {
    if (event.fromElement) {
        console.log("inactive");
        window.location.href = "http://google.com";
    }
    else {
        console.log("active");
    }
});
```

At the highest level possible, I'm trying to redirect the user once the app is launched.

Thanks in advance for any helpful input.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge -- and the few minutes I spent searching seems to confirm it -- there is no `success` callback available for that modal.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, Jeremy!